# Imposing column level security on a view for different user

Tags: oracle, vpd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Column level security](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24292/column-level-security)

I have a view which can be viewed by multiple users, and I would like to restrict some columns to specific users.

e.g I have a view with fields `A`, `B`... `F`, and I have users `P`, `Q`, `R`, `S`. Here's what I am trying to implement:

- when user `P` browses the view, he will see data in `A`, `B`, `C` and `F`, and columns `D` and `E` as `NULL`
- when user `Q` browses the view, he will see data in all fields
- when user `R` browses the view, he will see data in `A`, `D`, `E` and `F`, and columns `B` and `C` as `NULL`

Comment: See my answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24292/column-level-security/

Comment: I saw your answer which is more DBA dependent , my case is not like that . I want to implement the same by function or by something else in view source code itself.

Comment: @dibakarpaul you're asking how to do DBA level functionality, so why should it not be "dba dependent" as you word it? This is exactly what you need. This question is a duplicate of that, regardless the level of your ability.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- You can use synonyms (and as many views as there are different cases), as Phil showed in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/24293/558).
- This is a f[eature of Virtual Private Database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/vpd.htm#CIHDGJGD), included in the [Enterprise Edition](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/product-editions-066501.html).
- You can do it by hand with a little code

Here's an example of how you could do it yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE base_table (a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER, d NUMBER, e NUMBER, f NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE column_rights (username VARCHAR2(30) PRIMARY KEY,
                            a NUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER, d NUMBER, e NUMBER, f NUMBER);

INSERT INTO column_rights VALUES ('P', 1, 1, 1, 1, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO column_rights VALUES ('Q', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO column_rights VALUES ('R', 1, NULL, NULL, 1, 1, 1);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT b.a * c.a a,
       b.b * c.b b,
       b.c * c.c c,
       b.d * c.d d,
       b.e * c.e e,
       b.f * c.f f
  FROM base_table b
  JOIN column_rights c ON c.username = USER;

 GRANT SELECT ON my_view TO P; -- Q, R
```

The above assumes that all fields are NUMBER, but this would work with anything if you use `CASE`. This also assumes that the users are defined at the database level, but you could also use a custom identification scheme (replace USER by your function -- `V('USER')` in APEX).

In a more general setting, you could use a `COLUMN_RIGHTS` table with `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME` columns (this would unfortunately require N lookups where N is the number of columns).

You could also use a single `INTEGER` field or `RAW` field for the concatenated bit representation of the column rights so that all the information would still be in a single row and this could be used for multiple views.

Comment: Hi Vincent , Thanks for your answer . I have around 50 tables and each have more than 20 columns , so i am thinking will it be a good approach or not.